# Restangular extendModel Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, restangular

How to test Restangular.extendModel with Jasmine for example :

**Controller :**

```
  _this.populateSecurityGroups = function () {
    var netid = _this.instance.vm_fields.cloud_network * 1;
    CloudNetworksFactory.one(_this.provider, netid).then(
          function (net) {
            net.security_groups(_this.provider).then(
              function (sgs) { _this.security_groups = sgs; },
              function (err) {}
            );
          },
          function (err) {}
     );
  };
```

**Factory :**

```
    var all = function (provider) {
      return provider.getList('cloud_networks');
    };

    var one = function (provider, id) {
      var defered = $q.defer();
      this.all(provider).then(
        function (nets) {
          var res = _.find(nets.data, { id: id });
          defered.resolve(res);
        },
        defered.reject
      );
      return defered.promise;
    };

    Restangular.extendModel('cloud_networks', function (model) {
      model.security_groups = function (provider) {
        var _this = this;
        var defered = $q.defer();
        provider.security_groups().then(
          function (sgs) {
            var res = ...                
            defered.resolve(res);
          },
          defered.reject
        );

        return defered.promise;
      };

      return model;
    });
```

I can't test this function, first error is :

> undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'r.getList("cloud_networks")')
>
> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.security_groups')

This is the beginning of my test, i can't mock restangular.extendModel:

```
    it('should test populateCloudSubnets properly', function (done) {
      ctrl.instance.vm_fields.cloud_network = 1;
      ctrl.populateSecurityGroups().then(function(){
        ....
      }, function(err){
        expect(err).toBe(null);
        done();
      });

      $httpBackend.flush();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To test Restangular.extendModel with Jasmine you should use [Restangular.restangularizeElement](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#restangular-methods)

Taking by example that you have:

```
Restangular.extendModel('cloud_networks', function (model) {
  model.security_groups = function() {}
}
```

You can do this:

```
it('does something' function() {
  var model = {id: 1};
  Restangular.restangularizeElement(null, model, 'cloud_networks');

  // You can test model.security_groups() in here
}
```